# How do I estimate log10 of log10 of 8 billionth element of A000670?

Tags: combinatorics

How do I estimate log10 of log10 of the 8 billionth element of A000670 
as an actual number? I believe it's between 10 and 100, but am not 
sure why I believe this.

I realize http://oeis.org/A000670 offers some approximations of 
A000670 (in terms of n), but nothing that quickly leads to an actual 
value of log10(log10(a(n)))

Goal: I'm trying to calculate the number of possible "prejudices" in 
the world, and it's the nth element of A000670, where n is the current 
world population. I don't need an exact number, just something like 
10^(10^r) [to the nearest integer value for r], and I'm estimating n at about 8 billion right now.

Ideally, I'd like a good general estimate of log10(log10(a(n))) but 
that may be asking too much.

EDIT: It's easy to show A000670 is bounded by 2^n*n! (aka http://oeis.org/A000165), but this bound is loose and unhelpful.

http://oeis.org/A000670 notes "Unreduced denominators in convergent to log(2) = lim[n->inf, na(n-1)/a(n)].". Does this mean that: `n!*log(2)^n` would be an estimate, at least in terms of order of magnitude? It seems a bit low. Since log(2) < 1 this can't be right. Maybe

```
n!/(log(2)^n)
```

Comment: Is your bound $2^n\cdot n!$ or $2^{(n\cdot n!)}$?  These are a bit different.  Looking at the OEIS link, it is $2^n\cdot n!$

Comment: @RossMillikan You are correct, it's (2^n)*n!, but wouldn't that be implied by order of operations anyway?

Comment: Yes, it would, but we often have postings where the intent is not in agreement with the order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

See for instance Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*, p. 175, Example 5.2.1 "Ordered Bell Numbers" for the asymptotic
$$a(n) = n! \left(\frac{1}{2 \ln(2)^{n+1}} + O(0.16^n)\right).$$

It just arises from looking at the "leading singularity" of the exponential generating function. This approximation is particularly excellent since the first correction grows exponentially while the remaining correction decays exponentially.

Heuristically, Stirling's approximation says $\log_{10} \log_{10} (8 \cdot 10^9)!$ is going to be on the order of the exponent, namely 9--in fact, Mathematica tells me it's 10.879...--and the corrections are only going to contribute perhaps a few percent since even exponential growth is nothing compared to the growth of $n!$, so the nearest integer is definitely going to be 11.

We can be more precise though and actually prove it. Singularity analysis more fully gives

$$a(n) = \frac{n!}{2} \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln 2 + 2 \pi i k)^{n+1}},$$

the $k=0$ term of which gives the asymptotic above. Hence

$$\frac{1}{n!}\left|a(n) - \frac{1}{2 \ln(2)^{n+1}}\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\ln 2 + 2\pi i k|^{-(n+1)} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty (2\pi k)^{-(n+1)} = \frac{\zeta(n+1)}{(2\pi)^{n+1}}$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. This says

$$\log_{10} \log_{10} a(8 \cdot 10^9) = \log_{10} \log_{10} (8 \cdot 10^9)! \left(\frac{1}{2 \ln(2)^{8 \cdot 10^9+1}} \pm \frac{\zeta(8 \cdot 10^9 + 1)}{(2\pi)^{8 \cdot 10^9}}\right).$$

Mathematica is happy to compute $\log_{10} \log_{10}$ of this expression, say with 40 digits of precision. I've included some related expressions too.

[image: Mathematica estimates]

So, yup, the answer is 11.

Answer (score 0):

How close do you want to get?  If we use Stirling on your upper bound, we want $\log_{10}\log_{10}\frac{2^{8E9}8E9^{8E9}}{e^{8E9}}\sqrt {2\pi 8E9}= \log_{10}8E9(\frac 12+ \log_{10}\frac {16E9}e)+\frac 12\log_{10} 2\pi\approx 9+\log_{10}8+1\approx 11$

Comment: I'd like to get it to the nearest integer at least. When you say "use Stirling on your upper bound", could you be more explicit? I assume you're referring to a Stirling approximation, but wasn't sure. Also, are the "&E9" supposed to be "8E9" referring to 8 billion? Sorry, no offense intended, just a little hard to read your post.

Comment: Yes, I was using the Stirling approximation.  I don't see any "&E9"s, but if there are, they were intended to be $8E9$

Answer (score 0):

The OEIS comment

> `Unreduced denominators in convergent to log(2) = lim_{n->infinity} n*a(n-1)/a(n).`

suggests that there could be an asymptotic approximation proportional to $\frac{n!}{\log(2)^n}$ - you seem to have accidentally put the $\log(2)$ in the numerator. This is indeed correct and you also say [OEIS A000670](http://oeis.org/A000670) offers some approximations.  One is particularly good, and consistent with that earlier comment:

> `a(n) is asymptotic to (1/2)*n!*log_2(e)^(n+1), where log_2(e) = 1.442695... [Barthelemy80, Wilf90].`

i.e. $\dfrac{ n! }{2\, \log_e(2)^{n+1}}$

For example, while the actual term for $n=10$ is $102247563$, the approximation gives $102247563.005271$, almost exactly the same, and the relative error gets smaller for larger $n$.

If you apply the asymptotic formula to $n=8 \times 10^9$ you get about $3.6\times 10^{77023760357}$ which has a base-$10$ logarithm of about $77023760357.557 \approx 7.7\times 10^{10}$ and the base-$10$ logarithm of that base-$10$ logarithm is then about $10.8866247$

If you apply your upper bound of $2^n\, n!$ to $n=8 \times 10^9$ you get about $2.4\times 10^{78158604011}$ which has a base-$10$ logarithm of about $78158604011.372 \approx 7.8\times 10^{10}$ and the base-$10$ logarithm of that base-$10$ logarithm is then about $10.8929768$

There is an obvious lower bound of $n!$ (strict orderings) and applying that to $n=8 \times 10^9$ you get about $1.1\times 10^{75750364046}$ which has a base-$10$ logarithm of about $75750364046.060 \approx 7.6\times 10^{10}$ and the base-$10$ logarithm of that base-$10$ logarithm is then about $10.8793847$

So the answer is between $10^{10^{10}}$ and $10^{10^{11}}$, though you can be much more precise than that.